# Is there a proof of this identity: $(\mathbf{\nabla} \cdot \textbf{u})P = (\mathbf{\nabla} P) \cdot \textbf{u}$

Tags: vector-analysis

I want to verify if this vector identity is true and if so is there a simple proof of it? $\textbf{u}$ is a vector and $P$ is a scalar field, namely the pressure.

\begin{equation}
(\mathbf{\nabla} \cdot \textbf{u})P = (\mathbf{\nabla} P) \cdot \textbf{u}
\end{equation}

Comment: It does not seem this identity holds for any vector field $\textbf{u}$ and scalar $P$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Cartesian coordinates and using index notation one finds
\begin{equation}
(\nabla \cdot u) P = (\partial_i u_i) P
\end{equation} 
but on the other hand
\begin{equation}
(\nabla P)\cdot u = (\partial_i P) u_i
\end{equation}
In general these are not equal.

Notice that
\begin{equation}
(\nabla \cdot u) P = (\partial_i u_i) P = \partial_i (u_i P) -  (\partial_i P) u_i = \nabla\cdot(P u) - u\cdot\nabla P
\end{equation}
Even if $\nabla\cdot(P u) = 0$, there would be a sign difference with your statement.

Comment: Thank you, I see the problem.